# How to link a picture in specific object with hover popup and hyperlink

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I want to create something like this website: https://www.ukbathroomwarehouse.com/inspiration/scene2

So to link specific object of the picture with a plus, on mouse click to generate title and price of the product and hyperlink.

I did some research and till now didn't find what I need.

I found just this, but still now what I need exactly:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>The area coords attribute</h1>

<p>Click on the sun or on one of the planets to watch it closer:</p>

<img src="planets.gif" width="145" height="126" alt="Planets" usemap="#planetmap">

<map id="planetmap" name="planetmap">
<area shape="rect" coords="0,0,82,126" alt="Sun" href="sun.htm">
<area shape="circle" coords="90,58,3" alt="Mercury" href="mercur.htm">
<area shape="circle" coords="124,58,8" alt="Venus" href="venus.htm">
</map>

</body>
</html>
```

Can someone help me in this?

Comment: That site could be using javascript. You could try to view the source with ctrl + u. Maybe  that would give you an idea on the plugin

Comment: I saw just a class , and not too many details ...or maybe i don't know how to looks better

Comment: So you did check, good. I see some "css" that maybe responsible. Looks homegrown tho "/style/prettyPhoto.css". If you notice the html structure on the main page, you see that they use "img" tags. Shouldnt be too hard to reverse engineer this since they didn't minimize anything